# Call function from another jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".direction").click(function() {
        var direction = $(this).text();
```

When I click on a button with .direction class the second function above is called. When the left key is pressed I want to call the `$(".direction").click(function() {` But with a value (Instead of the var direction = $(this).text(); part) It would be var direction = value passed to function;

How can I do that?

Comment: If my answer on how to return the target event of the key code is not correct, (return the text of that element) please clarify your desired action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another function that is used by both methods:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
          move("left");
     }
});

$(".direction").click(function() {
     move($(this).text());
});

function move(newDirection)
{
     var direction = newDirection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use another function to do this instead of trying to trigger the click handler.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
        updateDirection("Something else");
    }
});

$(".direction").click(function() {
    updateDirection($(this).text());
});

function updateDirection(d) {
    var direction = d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var changeDirection = function(data) {
    var direction = data;
    alert(direction);
};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        changeDirection("your value here");
    }
});

$(".direction").click(function() {
    changeDirection($(this).text());
});​
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mEYhj/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to handle the event and then call it:

```
function handleMyEvent(direction){
     /* do your handling here */
}
$(document).keydown(function(e){ 
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {

        var direction = e.keyCode; // or create an appropriate string for your use
        // OR IF you want the value of the focused element, you can get that also:
        // IF this is not what you want/mean clarify please
        var direction = $(e.target).text();

        handleMyEvent(direction);
        return false; //still return false to prevent the default behavior
    } 
}); 

$(".direction").click(function() { 
    var direction = $(this).text();
    handleMyEvent(direction);
});
```